# What is the difference between data model and database model?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I've been exploring the concepts of data models and database models and have encountered varying perspectives on their definitions. Some sources suggest they are synonymous, while others posit that a data model serves as the foundation for a database model.

1. What precisely is a data model, and could you provide an example?
2. What constitutes a database model, and could you share an example?
3. What differentiates a data model from a database model?

I came across

> The database design/model stores the structure of the data and the links/relationships between data that should be stored to meet the users’ requirements. The database design is stored in the database schema, which is in turn stored in the data dictionary. A data model is a set or collection of constructs used for creating a database and producing designs for the databases.

Additionally, it introduces three components of a data model:

> 1. Structure: Identifying the structures used to store data through the provided data model structures.
> 2. Manipulation Language: The specific language used for data manipulations within a given model, known as data manipulation language.
> 3. Integrity Constraints: Rules that ensure data correctness in the database, maintaining it in a usable state for accurate information representation during database design.

Comment: The information technology industry often reuses and abuses many terms. **Context is everything.** To make this Question worthwhile, you’d have to provide specific details with specific samples. In doing so, the answer would likely be self-revealing.

Comment: To add further detail, edit your Question rather than posting Comments.

Answer (score 1):

If someone was to say "Data Model" to me I would assume they are talking about a data structure internal to the program most likely with respect to some Model/View approach (e.g. MVC, MVVM), so more focused on providing data for User Interface and service consumption and responding to changes to that data usually from the User Interface and services.

For Database Model I would assume they are looking at how they store this data within their database. Usually this is divided into a logical design, where the data is organised as per the database paradigm (e.g. relational) and then this leads to a physical design, which takes into account the limitations of the DB tech, as well as optimizations they want to include.

Comment: I am confused because of the following definition:  Database model "The
database design/model stores the structure of the data and the links/relationships between
data that should be stored to meet the users’ requirements. Database design is stored in
the database schema, which is in turn stored in the data dictionary."                          and another definition for data model:  " Data model is a set or collection of construct used for creating a database and producing
designs for the databases."

Answer (score 1):

The classical definition of Data Model (at least in the context of Database Design), is a set of abstraction mechanisms used to represent a part of the reality in order to build a database. For instance, in the Entity-Relationship Data Model one can represent the reality with Entities (weak and strong) and Relationships among them; in the Object-Oriented Data Model one can represent the reality through Objects, and the related mechanisms of Aggregation (on object is an aggregate of simple properties and other objets), Class (a class is a set of object having the same type) and Inheritance; in the Relational Data Model (the model adopted by Relational Database Systems) the reality is represented through tables (or more correctly relations) with keys, foreign keys and other types of constraints, etc.

On the other hand, the term Database Model usually is the name of the model of the reality, built with a specific Data Model; in other words, it corresponds to a particular schema in a certain Database Management System, representing a specific reality (i.e. the result of the design of a certain database). For instance, in an Database Model for a University, you have the entities Students, Courses, Faculty, with several associations among them and each of them with a certain sets of attributes.

Comment: sir i understood what is data model you have explained it in simple words, but still have problem in database model, what do you mean by "Particular schema", if you give an example it will become clear.

Comment: "For instance, in an Data Model for a University, you have the entities Students, Courses, Faculty, with several associations among them and each of them with a certain sets of attributes." Sir when we show the relationship between entities, it is data model then what is database model here in this example.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. The database model is the description of this set of entities, relationships and attributes given formally through a certain formalism based on a Data Model. For instance, you can specify graphically which are the entities, etc,, or you can use a textual formalism. In both cases you are formally modeling a certain reality.